# Forcing TLS 1.2 on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, tls

The question is about forcing Win7 to use TLS 1.2 only. (Yes, I know that Win7 gets no more patches, nevermind that.)

The underlying issue is that Ubisoft Connect does not work properly. The logs suggest that this is related to using the wrong version of TLS, I think. Log:

```
Http status code is 404 for url https://wallet.ecom.ubi.com/...
Http status code is none  for url https://channel-service.upc.ubi.com/...
```

(HTTP status code is none? Other calls in the logfile work normally, suggesting that there is some fundamental issue with the request itself. Like TLS problems. But maybe not, so I would like to be able to check if TLS 1.2 is configured as the only available protocol correctly - I suspect it isn't.)

Using SSLLabs, I looked at the supported TLS versions of those websites:

- https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=wallet.ecom.ubi.com
- https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=channel-service.upc.ubi.com

It seems the difference is that `wallet` supports **TLS 1.0 & 1.1** but not **1.3** and the `channel-service` doesn't support **1.0 & 1.1**, but does support **1.3**. (I'm not trying to use 1.3 though.)

Since **1.2** seems to be supported by both, that is the version I want Ubisoft Connect to use. So I'm trying to configure my Win7 to use **TLS 1.2 only**, and **not use 1.0/1.1 at all**. (Sadly, there is no support for 1.3.)

I already read through https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

### So, how can I **configure Windows 7 to use TLS 1.2 only** and **check whether the setting works properly**?

This is my registry:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/plan-design/security/enable-tls-1-2-client

Comment: Windows 7 fully supports TLS 1.2, if a Ubisoft application is not running properly on Windows 7 due to TLS, that is due to their application NOT supporting TLS 1.2 on Windows 7. **Windows 7 has zero support for TLS 1.3** The keys you have provided are only applicable to Internet Explorer by the way.

Comment: @fpmurphy I don't think Ubisoft Connect uses .NET Framework, their logs mention JobHttp.cpp for the lines I posted, and the other thing in your link is exactly what I posted in my screenshots.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, it appears it does not support it. But maybe that is because I've improperly set up TLS 1.2 somewhere. There is no reason not to support it though, so I'm wondering if there is anything I can do on my end to fix this, as I cannot fix their code. Maybe you can help me with my question please? "and check whether the setting works properly" <-- how can I check?

Comment: @AyCe - I know for a fact Windows 7 supports TLS 1.2, TLS 1.2 has been around for years, and Windows 7 only reached EOL in January 2020. Now it's certainly possible for the SSL module that Ubisoft Connect uses to make a secure HTTPS connection to NOT support Windows 7.  If Ubisoft indicates Windows 7 is not supported there isn't much you can do about that.

Comment: If something has gone wrong with TLS 1.2, follow [Update to enable TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 as default secure protocols in WinHTTP in Window](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392). Ensure you have the latest Windows 7 Service Pack installed and are fully updated.

Comment: @Ramhound Officially, Ubisoft games still support Windows 7, so I would expect it to work without problems. Ubisoft Connect used to work in February 2021, so I guess that the `channel-service` was configured not to use TLS 1.1 anymore some months ago, breaking the app for users of Win7, and it happened to work before because TLS 1.1 was still supported on the server-side. But that's just a theory. I don't know why they would explicitly prefer TLS 1.1 over 1.2 in their code, if, as you say, Win7 supports 1.2 "out of the box", with updates of course.

Comment: @harrymc Did you read my question? This is literally the same link that I posted. It does not tell you how to test if you did everything correctly. I'm not even sure how you could **not** have the latest patches installed on Win7. I also posted many screenshots, so instead of telling me "just look at this page you already looked at", check my screenshots if I set up everything correctly, please. I think I did. You telling me about the same page I already posted does not help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after all, here is the explanation. Maybe it is of use to someone else too.

The registry changes in `SCHANNEL\Protocols` are working fine. They can be tested with Internet Explorer. Firefox brings its own HTTPS code, so it's not possible to test with it.

When you set `Enable=0` on all HTTPS cryptographic protocols, no HTTPS websites will work in Internet Explorer anymore. Neither will Ubisoft Connect, you cannot even login anymore. I deactivated all of them, (SSL 2.0, SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1) with the exception of TLS 1.2. This way, TLS 1.2 will always be used. (Win7 does not support TLS 1.3.) The login then works again, as the server handling that, seems unaffected by the issue explained below.

The problem was, that https://channel-service.upc.ubi.com/ does not allow [any cipher suites supported by Windows 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7). And Windows 7 does not allow you to install new ones. The list of supported ones by the Ubisoft endpoint is rather small: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=channel-service.upc.ubi.com&s=54.147.167.217

```
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
```

[None of these seem to be available in Windows 7.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7)

This can be tested by using Internet Explorer to access both Github.com and the Ubisoft endpoint. Github will work, but the Ubisoft endpoint won't. Both sites use TLS 1.2, but Github allows for a larger variety of cipher suites: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=github.com

```
# TLS 1.2 (suites in server-preferred order)
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca9)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256P
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0xcca8)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256P
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS     256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK  256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK    256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK     256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH x25519 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9c)   WEAK   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9d)   WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x3c)   WEAK   128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x3d)   WEAK   256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)   WEAK  128
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)   WEAK  256
```

So the conclusion I draw from this, is that Ubisoft should add at least one of the [cipher suites supported in Windows 7](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-7) to the list of accepted ones for their endpoint server in question. That would be the sane, good solution. Are they going to do it? ... :|

My workaround "solution", was to spoof their endpoint server, by:

- Creating a self-signed certificate for the hostname `channel-service.upc.ubi.com`, installing it as a root certificate on my machine, and another one (with Windows 10) in my network. This is needed, as we will be pretending to be the Ubisoft endpoint, when we are in fact not. The HTTPS client only checks if the certificate chain goes back to some root certificate, which it does, as we just added it.
- Creating a webserver app with ASP.NET Core, that just receives connections, and "pipes" them to the real Ubisoft endpoint (the entire HTTP request), piping back the response. This is needed to accept a HTTPS connection and send back an appropriate response, encrypted by OUR server. (so not just TCP traffic forwarded)
- Adding an entry into the hosts file on my machine, to redirect `channel-service.upc.ubi.com` to the other machine in my network. This is needed so that Ubisoft Connect communicates with our webserver app, rather than try to make a request into the internet.
- Running the webserver app on the other (Windows 10) machine. This is needed because 1) we cannot connect to the actual Ubisoft endpoint on the machine with the hosts file modification and 2) we cannot use `HttpClient` to connect to the Ubisoft endpoint on a Windows 7 machine, as that fails, just as Internet Explorer and Ubisoft Connect fails. But it does work for Windows 10. It does also work for Java programs.

Now I am able to provide a "gateway"? "proxy"? for all machines running Windows 7 on my network to communicate with the actual Ubisoft endpoint. They just need the Root Certificate and the hosts file modification. Hooray, I can now play multiplayer games and use the chat again. :)

I guess you could also configure a real proxy? Hm, not sure.

Comment: why not use something simpler like that https://msfn.org/board/topic/183352-proxhttpsproxy-and-httpsproxy-in-windows-xp-for-future-use/ ? so no need for a win 10, i did not tested it in win 7 but it worked for me for xp, but it should work with win 7 it s the same principle